# Load cell noise filteration

Tags: digital-filters

I'm currently working in a project as apart of a student team.

## Setup

A platform is attached (placed over and screwed) two [1 Kg load cells](https://robu.in/product/weighing-load-cell-sensor-1kg-electronic-kitchen-scale-yzc-131-wires/) in order to measure the weight of the system. A vibration motor is also a part of the above mentioned system.

## Problem

The load cells, coupled with the entire setup causes noise while the vibration motor is switched on, preventing me to take real time data from the load cells, which is something I require.

## What I think

The mechanical stresses get amplified by the vibration motor, giving me erroneous readings. (because the load cells itself don't cause too much problems when tested separately)

Are there any filtering techniques I could use in order to be able to get better real time data from the load cells?

Answer (score 0):

> The mechanical stresses get amplified by the vibration motor, giving me erroneous readings.

Nothing to do with amplification. Basic high school-level physics!

"*Weight*" is just the force that an object exerts due to gravity acting on it. Your load cells hence simply measure the force pressing down on them, and, that's the whole idea of vibration motors, that is the sum of the gravity pull and the acceleration applied to the vibrating mass (see: Newton's laws: when your vibration motor moves some mass upwards, it's getting pushed down by a force identical to the lifting force, and vice versa).

> Are there any filtering techniques I could use in order to be able to get better real time data from the load cells?

Any kind of sufficiently low-cutoff low pass filter will do, because no matter how much you vibrate, the mass of the system doesn't change, and what goes up needs to come down.

You'd typically either simply do this with a mechanically dampening system, or with a simple RC low pass operating on your analog electrical signal, which you need for anti-aliasing anyway, because otherwise you're exposing your digital signal to aliases.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I get what's going on and will try the solution will try the solution.